# Multiple display form for custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, custom-list

I want to show different views to 2 different users for a custom list. Is it possible to add multiple display forms for a custom list in sharepoint 2013 ? How can we specify this? I need to do this based on the user permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment on Nadeem's answer, you can try using the [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.permissionsstring%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

The control

> conditionally renders the contents of the control to the current user
>   only if the current user has permissions defined in the
>   PermissionString
>
> **The content can be any HTML code or other controls**

So you can try to put into your page two SpSecurityTrimmedControls with different PermissionsString values and put a different DataFormWebPart in each.

If you try, let us know if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The form will be one only. However, you can write javascript client object model code along with Javascript/JQuery to show different information to users based on their permissions.

Comment: I wonder if SPSecurityTrimmedControl could be used to render different DataFormWebPart based on the user permission (by setting the PermissionsString property). I don't see why it shouldn't work. What do you think?

Comment: That is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In former SharePoint versions you could achieve this by applying conditional formatting inside custom list forms. I haven't tried it in SharePoint Designer 2013, though. It might be a bit more cumbersome without our beloved "Design View" but I guess the logic will still work.

See Laura's article for a detailed walkthrough (based on SharePoint 2007):
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=3&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0